# Responsive image without cropping

Tags: html, css, image, canvas, resize

I have two kinds of full-screen home pages, one using video and the other using images. I want both the image resize keeping the aspect radio Always respecting the size of the screen.

The full screen vídeo template is working fine for me. I'm using the code below:

```
<div style="background-color: #000000;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 997;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;">
<video autoplay poster="img/jerusalem.jpg" id="bgvid" loop style="
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    z-index: 998;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
    <source src="video/jerusalem.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/jerusalem.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/jerusalem.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
</div>
```

but i'm having troubles with the full screen image template, i already tried to use the same code but it doesn't work for me

```
<div style="background-color: #000000;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 997;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;">
    <img src="img/bg1.jpg" style="
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

    z-index: 998;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
</div>
```

i already tried to use, the code below, but in this case the image doesn't increase.

```
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
```

Someone can help me? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using css properties of image i.e.

```
.imageclass
{
   width:100%
   height: auto;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: contain; /* or cover , etc  */
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no repeat;

}
```

in above CSS, background-size:contain; property re-size image with respect to the content and re-size itself.

Comment: thank you, but i'm using `width:100%; height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<img>` try using `background-image` as follows:

```
.image_box {
background-image: url("img/bg1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
}
```

use this class for your `<div>`.

also, you can play with streching using `background-size: contain/etc...`

Please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp for more background-size information.